# Appending multiple divs with date IDs

Tags: jquery, date, calendar, append

I'm trying to create sort of a lifestream, in which I would display tweets and such. Anyway, I'm at the beginning, and I'm stuck on something that must be quite easy but that I can't figure out.

I'm trying to append to a container a series of divs (30 to be exact) in a way that each div has a class/ID with the date it concerns. I already have a date variable containing the current date in the format dd-mm-yyyy . I would like to append to my container something like :

```
<div class="entry" id="12-05-2011">
</div>
<div class="entry" id="11-05-2011">
</div>
<div class="entry" id="10-05-2011">
</div>
etc...
```

the first one being dated at the current date.

Do you have any ideas on how to do this ?

Thanks in advance !

Here is my date code :

```
var time = new Date();
var day = time.getDate();
var month = time.getMonth() + 1;
if(month < 10){
month = "0" + month;
}
var year = time.getFullYear();
var date = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
```

Comment: No answer from me; but a quick comment.  How likely is it that you're only going to have one post per day?  If you have more than one per day, then you'll end up with non-unique Id's and it will confound any javascript you write.

Comment: The divs will contain multiple posts from that day. :)

Comment: one min, making a fiddle

Comment: ID to be valid html     Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
   Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")
    Values are case-sensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some JS you can do:

```
date_counter = {
    current_day: (new Date()).getDate(),
    current_month: (new Date()).getMonth(),
    current_year: (new Date()).getFullYear(),
    get_date: function(days_past){
        var time = new Date(this.current_year, 
                            this.current_month, 
                            (this.current_day)+days_past);
        var day = time.getDate();
        var month = time.getMonth() + 1;
        if (month < 10) {
            month = "0" + month;
        }
        var year = time.getFullYear();
        var date = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
        return date
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
{
    console.log(date_counter.get_date(i));
    var date = date_counter.get_date(i);
    $the_div = $('<div>', {
        id: 'date_' + date, //to have correct types of ids (see comments below)
        text: 'Content for ' + date
    });
    $the_div.appendTo(document.body);
}
```

And here is the fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/zrnnP/

Comment: wow great stuff thx ! I actually needed the day to be sequential, but I'll try to make the changes myself and get back to you ! I'm quite new to javascript and honestly, I know it's bad but I started directly with jQuery, so I'm still a bit lost when it comes to pure javascript hehe...

Comment: nooo problem :-D remember to select an `accepted` answer when you can :-D

Comment: Arf, I'm trying to modify the code to fit my goal, but can't get it to work... Would you mind modifying it so it meets my question : Sequential days in a descending order starting from the actual date ? I'd be really grateful :)

Comment: well i did 30 months, you want 30 days?

Comment: yep if possible :D. Same system but one level down. Year doesn't matter, but cross-months would be great ! (it's an experiment, so I don't mind the 30-31 days difference) Cheers !

Comment: @neal I have no doubt that this works and I'm sure you know but please see my comment on question

Comment: @mcgrailm, im not saying its correct html, im just going by what the OP wants. i can add you comment as an addendum to my answer if you want

Comment: Oh right yeah forgot about that hehe Anyway got it to work ! Thanks a lot to both of you !

Comment: Yep did accept yours, even if I'm thankful to both of you ! But the final code is 90% yours hehe. I dunno why, at first it wasn't working on my page, but I replaced the appending part with jQuery and voila, it worked !

Comment: @charles, the newer version of my code also makes use of javascript object (in which you can use the `this` variable)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Neal's answer is so complex. Maybe I'm missing something, but the following seems to work for me...

```
var date = new Date()
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);

while(date <= new Date()) {
    $('#container').append(getDateDiv(date));
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
}

function getDateDiv(date) {
    return '<div id="' + getDateString(date) + '"></div>';
}

function getDateString(date) {
   // note that months are 0 indexed
   return date.getDate() + '-' 
       + (date.getMonth() + 1) 
         + '-' + date.getFullYear();
}
```

**EDIT** just seen you want descending order, so...

```
var date = new Date()
var counter = 0;
while(counter <= 30)
{
    $('#container').append(getDateDiv(date));
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
    counter++;
}
```

As an aside, I'd recommend using the date in `yyyymmdd` format instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems much easier ! But with this solution, we're appending during a loop right ? Isn't that a bit hard on the browser ?

Comment: Not really, unless you want to show history for the last few decades :). You could hoist the `$('#container')` jQuery selector into a variable outside the loop to improve performance if it bothers you.

Comment: @fearodwhack, i changed my answer

Comment: @Charleshaa re performance concerns, I just ran this in jsFiddle and it took 2 milliseconds for 30 divs. Creating 10000 divs takes around a second. Computers are pretty fast these days! See here: http://jsfiddle.net/eLKzU/

Comment: Can you tell me why you would use yyyymmdd ? Cheers

Comment: @Charles Its the standard date format used because it allows sorting in numeric order.